# how to do pipe to src attribute angular

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

If I do: `<h2>{{event.role | lowercase}}</h2>`. However, if I try to use it in an `src` attribute like this:

```
<img src={{event.eventName | lowercase}} alt="">
```

I get the error:

```
core.js:6237 ERROR DOMException: 
Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '|' is not a valid attribute name.
```

It is not recognizing the pipe, however, not using the pipe works correctly so the format `{{event.eventName}}` seams to work. How should I do it?

Comment: What about adding quotes around?

Comment: The solution is as you said! I just did `src="{{ event.eventName | lowercase }}"` Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use quotes around the expression, otherwise angular will not be able to parse your expression

```
<img src="{{ event.eventName | lowercase }}" alt=""
```

Or

```
<img [src]="event.eventName | lowercase" alt=""
```

Answer (score 5):

To use pipes with variables that are bound to properties, you could wrap it in a container with a `*ngIf` directive. It also allows you to apply the pipe once and reuse the modified variable multiple times. Try the following

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="event.eventName | lowercase as name">
  <img [src]="name" alt="">

  <!-- reuse the variable with the pipe applied -->
  <img [src]="name" alt="">
</ng-container>
```